# what did i do wrong while implementing slug url in django?

Tags: python, django, slug

I am getting the following error after I modified the urls.py, views.py and models.py file in my blog application to accomodate a slug string in the url.

> Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 3}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[-\w\d]+),(?P\d+)/$']

I am attaching the link to the github repository for the project here, as I don't have any idea what went wrong please let me know where to look.
[git repository](https://github.com/ankushv72/blog-assgmt.git)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you have a comma in your pattern, did you mean to use a slash?

```
'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+),(?P<pk>\d+)/$'
#                   ^ ??
```

Also, the error indicates you're passing only the `'pk'`. However, now that that pattern has been updated with a `'slug'` parameter, you need to pass this also.

Comment: 'Slug' parameter needs to be passed to what? the view? or the template?

Comment: I am fetching the post using the pk - primary key, but in the url I want to display the slug only

Comment: `slug` needs to be passed to your `reverse` function.